# Mysql query select sum() only if condition met group by

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website that contains a competition in betting

What I want to do is select TOP 10 player in this month from table called matches

Here is the photo of mysql table

[image]

I need mysql query that will SELECT SUM(moguci_dobitak) FROM matches only if rezultat='win' AND date is current month and current year GROUPED BY user

translation

moguci_dobitak = profit

rezultat = result

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(moguci_dobitak) 
FROM matches 
WHERE rezultat='win' 
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT SUM(moguci_dobitak) 
FROM matches 
WHERE rezultat='win' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM matches where rezultat='win' and  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date_col group by User;